# Is there an app to automatically format CSS files?

Tags: css

I have a compressed CSS file (all whitespace removed) that I want to inspect, but it's a huge pain inspecting it as-is.  Is there any utility (preferably linux command line) that I can run the file through to format it nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a little formatter in Ruby for you. Save it as some `.rb` file and use it via CLI like `ruby format.rb input.css input-clean.css`:

```
#Formats CSS

input, output = ARGV

#Input
if input == nil or output == nil
    puts "Syntax: #{$0} [input] [output]"
    exit
end

#Opens file
unless File.exist? input
    puts "File #{input} doesn't exist."
    exit
end

#Reads file
input = File.read input
#Creates output file
output = File.new output, "w+"

#Processes input
input = input.gsub("{", "\n{\n\t")
         .gsub(",", ", ")
         .gsub(";", ";\n\t")
         .gsub(/\t?}/, "}\n\n\n")
         .gsub(/\t([^:]+):/, "\t" + '\1: ')

#Writes output
output.write input

#Closes output
output.close
```

Comment: Not working 100% for me, but I can probably tweak it easily (doesn't seem to like the newlines before the .gsub calls and is complaining about non-escaped {} in the regex. Maybe a ruby version difference?).  Thanks!

Comment: @Herms, the String#gsub method takes as the first argument simple strings ("" or '') or regular expressions (//) (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817). Newlines are just a syntax sugar in Ruby. ;-)

Comment: Yea, but for some reason stringing them together like you did fails. If I remove the newlines so it's just input.gsub().gsub().gsub()... it works.

Comment: With the newlines like you had it I get `format.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting $end`

Comment: @Herms, oh, I'm sorry. I use Ruby 1.9.1 and it can handle this.

Comment: Here's a link to what I got working and behaving the way I needed (ruby 1.8.7): http://gist.github.com/500644

Comment: Going to accept this one as, one, you were awesome and actually built something for me, and it's also the one I can get to behave the most like I need.

Comment: nice job. after fixing that \n before { it's usable. thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The online service that Dave Newman mentioned has been converted into a Node.js script, which you can run on the command-line. If you have NPM installed you can just do:

```
npm install -g cssunminifier
```

And it’s pretty versatile how you can use it. Here are 3 different examples:

```
cssunminifier style.min.css style.css
cssunminifier --width=8 style.min.css
curl http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css | cssunminifier - | less
```

Here’s more info on the [command-line css unminifier](http://mrcoles.com/blog/command-line-css-unminifier-utility/)

Comment: It's nice that this also allows to replace a file with its pretty-printed version. So you can do, for example after saving a web page in Firefox as "Webpage, complete": `for file in *.css; do cssunminifier $file $file; done`

Comment: FYI: This tool requires Node v11.15.0 or earlier to work because it relies on the very old `puts()` method in the node `utils` module, which was removed in v12. If you really want to use it, use NVM to install and use that version before installing it globally. Don't forget to change back to a more modern version of afterwards!

Answer (score 5):

Try [this online service](http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/).

You can also inspect any compressed file in Firebug.

Comment: Was looking at the file in chrome's dev tools, but it wasn't formatting it at all.

Comment: That online service has also been converted into a versatile command line utlity with Node.js https://github.com/mrcoles/cssunminifier – see the readme on that page for how to use it

Answer (score 3):

These programs are called 'beautifiers'. You should be able to google one that fits for you.

Comment: *That*'s the word! I knew there was a term for it but I was drawing a complete blank.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a locally-executable utility, as opposed to a web service, you want [CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Locally-executable is preferable.  CSST Tidy isn't perfect (doesn't indent), but it's the closest so far to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This also indents: [styleneat](http://www.styleneat.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free windows app to "beautify" your file. I haven't used it so I don't know how well it works.
http://www.blumentals.net/csstool/

Comment: Windows apps don't really help me. I've got an ubuntu machine and a mac laptop, so I really need something that would work on one of those.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It is specific, but Visual Studio does this on that file type. (by no means a generic solution to which you alude)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the **vkBeautify** plugin

http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/

It can beautify (pretty print) CSS, XML and JSON text,

written in plain javascript, small, simple and fast