# How to format CSS in a single line using awk macOS (POSIX)

Tags: awk, grep, gsub

Input file is minified css file:

```
.class{margin:0px}.class1,.class2{margin 0px}@media{.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}@media{.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}@media{.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX{color:blue}}@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}@media only screen and (inverted-colors){.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}.classV{color:red}.classR{color:red}.classU{color:red}.classS{color:red}.classT{color:red}}.classNew{margin: 10px}
```

Expected result:

```
.class{margin:0px}
.class1,.class2{margin 0px}
@media{.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media{.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media{.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media only screen and (inverted-colors){.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}.classV{color:red}.classR{color:red}.classU{color:red}.classS{color:red}.classT{color:red}}
.classNew{margin: 10px}
```

When I use this:

```
awk '{gsub(/\t?}/, "}\n"); print}'
```

It gives following result which does not match with expected result above:

```
.class{margin:0px}
.class1,.class2{margin 0px}
@media{.class{color:blue}
.class1,.class2{color:red}
}
@media{.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}
}
@media{.classD,.classE{color:blue}
.class1,.class2{color:red}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.class{color:blue}
.class1,.class2{color:red}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}
}
@media only screen and (inverted-colors){.classD,.classE{color:blue}
.class1,.class2{color:red}
.classV{color:red}
.classR{color:red}
.classU{color:red}
.classS{color:red}
.classT{color:red}
}
.classNew{margin: 10px}
```

Here is my idea to get expected result:

*find {

then

after that check if next char is } or {

if }

then

add new line after }

if {

after that check if next char is }}

if }}

then

add new line after }}

go through the input file*

Comment: If your proposed approach doesn't work the way you would like it to, could you say how it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: This might help: [Is there an app to automatically format CSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3372060/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**two-step `awk` procedure**

I have a procedure that works for your example but have had to re-interpret the rules and it is possible it may not work for every case you wish to process if my rules are wrong (apologies if so).

**interpretation**

The process I was aiming for is:

> 1. If the first-opened `{` style block on a line is closed (`}`) before another is opened, a new line begins immediately following the closure of that block.
> 2. An `@media` rule can only be at the start of a line.
> 3. for a block containing other blocks, and so ending with `}}`, a new line always follows the double closure.

**overview of approach**

The procedure uses two `awk` procedures, the first receiving its input from the data file, the second taking its input from the output of the first. I will first explain their workings separately before giving the combined procedure, joined using a pipe.

**first awk step**

This first `awk` step modifies the input line to take account of *rule 3* above (that `}}` can only be at the end of a line). This is achieved by setting the `awk` field separator to a double closure using `FS="}}"`. A loop is used to print each field (followed by the `}}` which is otherwise lost) causing `awk` to separate the fields onto their own lines with its default output record separator `ORS` (a new line):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="}}"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i"}}"; print $NF}' mini.css
```

This first `awk` step results in the following output (this does not need to be saved to a file as it will be 'piped' into the second `awk` procedure later):

```
.class{margin:0px}.class1,.class2{margin 0px}@media{.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media{.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media{.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media only screen and (inverted-colors){.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}.classV{color:red}.classR{color:red}.classU{color:red}.classS{color:red}.classT{color:red}}
.classNew{margin: 10px}
```

Note at this stage, all lines, except the last, terminate with `}}` and `}}` never exists internally in a line. *rule 3* above is satified by this step.

**second awk step**
The second `awk` step receives the above output from the first step via a pipe. It performs two functions:

***Firstly***, the procedure checks to see if the first opening block `{` on a line is closed `}` before another is opened. If it is closed, a new line is introduced for the remainder of the line, unless, for the specific case where a second `}` occurs after only one opening `{` as in the third line of the output above `@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}}` (this may have been a typo in your original file where the `(` following `.classX` was intended to be `{`). The check will become irrelevant but harmless if it was a typo and is corrected. (see closing note for correction).

The check is made by dividing the input line into fields separated by `{`. The field separator is set in a `BEGIN` block. At the same time the output field separator is set to the same opening brace, to replace `{` when the fields are printed:

```
BEGIN{FS="{"; OFS="{"}
```

Now, if there is an occurrence of `}` in field 2, then it closes the  first block before another was opened and so a line break is inserted after the closure using substitution:

```
$2~"}"{if (NF>2) sub("}","}\n",$2);}
```

Note the use of the condition `pattern` `$2~"}"`, which only applies the action if `}` appears in field 2. This satifies *rule 1* above.

***Secondly***, the procedure examines each field after the first to see if it contains a media querie, if `@` is present a substitution is made to insert a line break before it so that the media querie begins a new line (*rule 2*).

A final `action` block in the second `awk` procedure prints the modified line.

The second procedure in its entirety follows (note this won't function without the output of the first procedure being piped into it or supplied as a file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="{"; OFS="{"} $2~"}"{if (NF>2) sub("}","}\n",$2);} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) sub("@","\n@",$i)} {print}'
```

**whole procedure**

Here are the two procedures combined by pipe:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="}}"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i"}}"; print $NF}' mini.css | awk 'BEGIN{FS="{"; OFS="{"} $2~"}"{if (NF>2) sub("}","}\n",$2);} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) sub("@","\n@",$i)} {print}'
```

Note the data file, named `mini.css` in this case, is the argument to the first `awk` procedure. The output from the first procedure is piped into the second.

**test results**

(Tested on Mac Terminal using GNU Awk 5.2.0)

This is the output of the single line example data in the question, saved as `mini.css`, and processed using the combined `awk` scripts above under *whole procedure*:

```
.class{margin:0px}
.class1,.class2{margin 0px}
@media{.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media{.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media{.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media only screen and (inverted-colors){.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}.classV{color:red}.classR{color:red}.classU{color:red}.classS{color:red}.classT{color:red}}
.classNew{margin: 10px}
```

**note regarding possible typo**
If this part of the original data:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}}
```

was intended to be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX{color:blue}}
```

then the `if (NF>2)` in the second procedure becomes redundant. The working joined procedures, would then be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="}}"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i"}}"; print $NF}' mini.css | awk 'BEGIN{FS="{"; OFS="{"} $2~"}"{sub("}","}\n",$2);} {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) sub("@","\n@",$i)} {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[^}]*}}?([^}]*}})?/&\n/g' input_file
.class{margin:0px}
.class1,.class2{margin 0px}
@media{.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
@media{.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}
@media{.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}
```

Comment: thank u.. it does not work for large number of classes or large css file.

Comment: for ex: @media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classX(color:blue}}@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.class{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}}@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px){.classA.classB,.classC{margin:0px}}@media only screen and (inverted-colors){.classD,.classE{color:blue}.class1,.class2{color:red}.classV{color:red}.classR{color:red}.classU{color:red}.classS{color:red}.classT{color:red}}.classNew{margin: 10px}

Comment: @SharadShrestha What is the expected output for the sample? It seems to work on my end albeit a misplaced curly bracket

Comment: I have updated input file and expected result.